# how can I find and isolate a qr code in a complex image?

Tags: image

Using MatLab I need to find qr codes in a image database.
Then I need to isolate this qr code.
finaly I'll use the ZXing to decode the info.

*the images will always have just one QR Code.

Answer (score 0):

[ZXing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/) includes a QR code detector as well as a decoder, so you could, in theory, pass every image to ZXing and see if it finds a code.

That said, the ZXing detector is tuned for images from cell-phone like cameras and may not work too well on an image set that has very different characteristics without some kind of preprocessing.